# Calculating amount of water needed to increase humidity to target Humidity

Tags: temperature, humidity

We are currently working on a greenhouse startup project. And we want to be able to maintain the humidity inside our greenhouse. Given we know the outside temperature and humidity. And also the temperature and humidity inside of our greenhouse. Is there a way to calculate how much water is needed to reach target humidity?

(dimensions are not big. 75 x 45 x 38 cm)

Comment: Sure there is. Any research effort from your side so far?

Comment: ive looked up relative humidity calculator, and there is a bit of info. although the only real calculator i could find was not measuring with enough decimals. And i am always curios. i love knowing the theory behind it aswell, which the calculator does not explain

Comment: My impression is that all the calculations of relative humidity are related to the calculation of the dew point, which seems to be (a rather complicated) science of its own. Wikipedia shows how to calculate approximately the [water partial pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_humidity#Measurement). Plug this into a real gas equation for water vapor....That's the way I would try it. There are tables, graphs, and online calculators, though.